# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keys_keys.txt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

As I'm working with files and cryptography library, I'm have problem reading file. Details are as follows,

Getting following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCharm Python Works/OpenCity/main_directory/main_file.py", line 8, in <module>
    fe.encrypt_file(z2[0], z2[1])
  File "F:\PyCharm Python Works\OpenCity\cryptograph\file_encryptor.py", line 4, in encrypt_file
    keys = kr.read_keys()
  File "F:\PyCharm Python Works\OpenCity\cryptograph\key_reader.py", line 3, in read_keys
    f1 = open('keys.key', 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keys.key'
```

cryptograph
file_decryptor.py:

```
def decrypt_file(x, y):

    from cryptograph import key_reader as kr
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    keys = kr.read_keys()
    key = keys[0]
    input_file = x
    output_file = y

    with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    f1 = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f1.decrypt(data)

    with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(encrypted)
```

file_encryptor.py:

```
def encrypt_file(x, y):
    from cryptograph import key_reader as kr
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
    keys = kr.read_keys()
    key = keys[0]
    input_file = x
    output_file = y

    with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    f2 = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = f2.encrypt(data)

    with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(encrypted)
```

key_reader.py:

```
def read_keys():
    from typing import List
    f1 = open('keys.key', 'rb')
    f2: List[bytes] = []
    data: bytes
    for data in f1:
        f2.append(data)
    print(f2)
    return f2
```

main_file.py:

```
from cryptograph import file_encryptor as fe
from cryptograph import file_decryptor as fd
z1r = open('files.txt', 'r')
z2 = []
for data in z1r:
    data = data.rstrip('\n')
    z2.append(data)
fe.encrypt_file(z2[0], z2[1])
fd.decrypt_file(z2[1], z2[2])
```

I have just completed the premium category.
The crytograph is the problem. Everything is OK, except the main_file which is causing problems.

Comment: Is your file keys.key stored at "F:\PyCharm Python Works\OpenCity\cryptograph\" ?

Comment: Error:  No such file or directory: 'keys.key'. Make sure you have file 'keys.key' available and use absolute path(Complete path).

Comment: @SunPaz it is there in the same category. But the main_file is in the different category.

Comment: @naveentamanam I will try and tell you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the directory using `os.chdir()` helped me to fix this issue.

Code for reference:

```py
import cryptograph.key_writer

key_writer.write_key('keys.key', 1)
```

cryptograph/key_writer.py

```
import os


def write_key(file, number_of_keys):
    # create key
    keys = []
    for i in range(number_of_keys):
        key.append(create_key())

    os.chdir('./cryptograph')
    # write keys to file
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        for key in keys:
            f.write(key)
    return None # it is fine not to have this return stmt, but I like to have it.
```

Answer (score 1):

The exact reason of the error is

```
"File "F:\PyCharm Python Works\OpenCity\cryptograph\key_reader.py", line 3, in 
read_keys
f1 = open('keys.key', 'rb')"
```

It blames there is not keys.key file.
So, you should confirm that there is "keys.key" file exists in "F:\PyCharm Python Works\OpenCity\cryptograph\" directory.

Comment: How to add them sir. Can you please give me a syntax sir?

Comment: but sir when i distribute to everyone the directory takes the problem sir

Comment: Having `os.chdir` helped me to fix this problem after long time.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `keys.key` file is saved at the same location as your `key_reader.py`.

Or use an absolute path instead, e.g.:

```
f1 = open('F:/path/to/file/key.key', 'rb')
```

Comment: Sir it is saved on the same location as my key_reader.py is located. It also works when using with key_reader.py, file_encryptor.py and file_decryptor.py, but it doesn't work with main_file.py.

Comment: I could have just used `os.chdir` but I learnt about it after a long time, so, it's fine.

I've posted a answer with it.